# I use openMP to make my computation quick,but it doesn't work.Why?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

- I have a computation with a matrix(88147*2000) and it runs very slow.
- So I want to use openMP to speed it up. This is my first time to use
  openMP so I just use it in "loop-for".

This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<math.h>
#include<omp.h>
using namespace std;

#define LONGTH 88147
int label[LONGTH] ;
float data[LONGTH][2000] ;
float w[2000];
float e[2000];

void Input()
{
    ifstream fin;
    float a;
    fin.open("/home/data.train");
    if (!fin)
    {
            cout << "file error";
            return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < LONGTH; i++)
    {
            fin >> a;
            label[i] = int(a);
            for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
            {
                    fin>>data[i][j];
            }
    }
    fin.close();
    cout<<"input over"<<endl;
    return;
}
void Initial()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
            w[i] = 1;
            e[i] = 1;
    }
    return;
}

bool End()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
            if (fabs(e[i])>pow(0.1, 6))
                    return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

float Tkj(int i, int j, int k,float w[2000])
{
    return w[i] * data[k][i] - w[j] * data[k][j];
}

float En(int n)//*computation*
{
    float result = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(64) reduction(+:result)
    for (int k = 0; k < LONGTH; k++)
    {
            int tnum = omp_get_thread_num();
            float tmp = 0;
            int i = label[k] - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
            {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                            float l = 0;
                            if (n == i)
                            {
                                    l = data[k][i];
                                    float e = exp(Tkj(i, j, k,w));
                                    tmp = tmp + (-e*l) / pow(1 + e, 2);
                            }
                            else if (n == j)
                            {
                                    l = -data[k][j];
                                    float e = exp(Tkj(i, j, k,w));
                                    tmp = tmp + (-e*l) / pow(1 + e, 2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    continue;
                            }                       
                    }
            }
            result = result + tmp;
    }
    return result;
}
float Ex(float w[2000])
{
    float result = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(64) reduction(+:result)
    for (int k = 0; k < LONGTH; k++)
    {
            int i = label[k] - 1;
            float tmp = 0;
            int tnum = omp_get_thread_num();
            for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
            {
                    if (j != i)
                    {
                            tmp = tmp + 1 / (1 + exp(Tkj(i,j,k,w)));
                    }
            }
            result = result+tmp;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Input();
    Initial();
    float w2[2000] = { 0 };
    float b = pow(0.1,5);
    int times = 0;
    while (!End()&&times<=30000)
    {
            times++;
            cout<<times<<endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                    e[i] = En(i);
                    w2[i] = w[i] - b*e[i];
            }
            if (Ex(w2)<=Ex(w))//better
            {
                    b = b * 2;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
                            w[i] = w2[i];
            }
            else//worser
            {
                    b = b / 2;
            }
    }
    ofstream fout("/home/w.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<2000;i++)
    {
            fout<<w[i]<<' ';
    }
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

- The function 'En' costs most of time,so I use "#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(64) reduction(+:result)"to speed it up.
- I run it in a CentOS server which has 32 cores and use "-fopenmp" to compile it.But it doesn't be a little quicker.
- How can I speed this program up more?

Comment: Can't you expand the inner loop? If `n == i` the loop goes for all `j` values (except `j == i`) and this for loop can be parallelized, otherwise, you only need the case for `j == n` and there is no need for a loop. Othe than that, because the inner loop takes varying time to compute for each thread, you probably should add `schedule(dynamic)` directive as well. Also, if you only have 32 cores, do you get any benefits from using 64 threads?

Comment: This doesn't address your actual problem, but if you move the declarations of `tnum`, `tmp`, and `i` into the body of the `j` loop, so that there's no code between the start of the `k` loop and the start of the `j` loop, you can use OpenMP's `collapse(2)` to parallelize both levels of the nested loop.  The full iteration space of `LONGTH * 2000` iterations will be divided among the threads.

Comment: Is the bigdata tag trolling? It's not a meaningful term but even the fake meaning people attach to it doesn't seem to apply here.